# Why does a row set to full-width has a width of 89% in Divi theme?

Tags: wordpress, themes

In Divi when I create a simple row and set that row to "full width", its width in CSS is actually 89%:

```
.et_pb_row.et_pb_row_fullwidth, .et_pb_specialty_fullwidth>.et_pb_row {
    width: 89%!important;
    max-width: 89%!important;
}
```

Why and how to solve that problem? Note: my row contains two columns.

Comment: there is too few information for getting answers. does your added css rules working? in which file it overriding? what css you added? provide html code

Comment: There's no HTML code at all. If I create a new page in WP, then a new Divi section, then the row within that section will always have a width of 89% instead of 100% even if the row is set to full width.

Comment: There is no HTML code. If I create a new WP page, then a Divi section in it, and set the row within that section to full width, it will not be full width but instead have a width of 89%.

Comment: everything,which you see in your browser, contain pure html.

Comment: I mean there is no HTML code needed to replicate the problem pointed out here since I didn't write any.

Comment: provide your link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows are set to `max-width:89/90%` combine with `margin-left/right:auto` to maintain gutters on either side of the content.

You'll want to use a full-width section & not a specialty-section. If needed you can add custom-classes to the section. I've found it's best to add classes at the top-level (on the sections, not any of their rows or modules).

If needed, you can deque the module shortcodes, rewrite them yourself & then remove / re-add their shortcode handles. This article explains it well: https://jonathanbossenger.com/building-your-own-divi-builder-modules/

From: `Customizer >> General Setting >> Website Content Width` you can set the max-width of the main contents.

This should do the trick, unless it's being intercepted by inline-styles. The `.et_pb_column` element might be getting in the way as well.

Try adding the following to the Additional-CSS section in the customizer.

```
.et_pb_row.et_pb_row_fullwidth {
    width: 100%!important;
    max-width: 100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Side comment about Divi: I find it mind-blowing that a mature page builder like Divi lacks such an elemental layout feature as a true full-width row. That's disappointing to say the least, although it's not as bad as the countless settings I've applied in the back-end that ended up not working on the front-end. The whole thing seems quite buggy. It's my first use though so maybe it's me who's buggy :)

Comment: No problem @drake035. I agree. That's one of the caveats of wysywyg / drag&drop layout editors: They often contain so many options to make things accessible for non-developers that those same options cause all kinds of unexpected issues for developers (the solutions for which are terribly simple, just difficult to find if you don't know where to look), yet are missing the one option you really need.

Answer (score 3):

It's coming from `Divi Builder Settings`. You can easily make them `100% width`.

Just open the page, which you want to change and go to `Edit page`. Use builder of theme by clicking to `Use The Divi Builder`: 
[image: Divi builder button]

After click options button ( I marked it red in the image below ):

[image: Divi builder bar]

You'll see popup with some options. Find `Gutter Width` and set its value to 1:

[image: Divi builder popup with settings]

Click `Save` button and then `Update` page( use default wordpress sidebar at right side of your page):

[image: wp sidebar]

You can check your page. The css rules you provided will ovveride with `width: 100%` by just `Divi settings`:

[image: css]

P.S. You should make this changes for all pages, where you want to have `100% width`. If you want all pages have `100% width` by default, then you should go to: `Appreance -> Customize -> General Settings -> Layout Settings`, change value of `Website Gutter Width` to 1 and append changes ( at the top of sidebar click `Save & Publish` button )

Comment: Thanks but beyond achieving what I want, it will also remove column gutters which is not what I want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code insted of your current css

```
.et_pb_row.et_pb_row_fullwidth,
.et_pb_specialty_fullwidth .et_pb_row {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```